# Angular2: Can custom input know if its invalid?

Tags: angular

I have a custom input component `<datepicker>` with custom value accessor for some third-party datepicker widget.

I can use it in other components like this:

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="model.date" required></datepicker>
```

I want to apply a specific style to it when it's invalid.

The problem is Angular applies `ng-invalid` class to the `<datepicker>` element itself, and I can't have style like

```
datepicker.ng-invalid {
    border-color:red;
}
```

in component's local style, because local style doesn't cover element itself, only its descendants.

The only option I see is to put this css rule into global stylesheet, but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your idea behind. Why don't you put your "required" attribute into the template of datepicker component?

Comment: Because the whole point of creating custom input is to make it reusable. Some datepickers in a form may be required, some not.

Comment: You can put an input in your component like [required]="true" and use "required" variable in your datepicker componen template

Answer (score 0):

You can style components root via special [:host](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host) pseudo-class selector.

In your case it would be something like:

```
:host(.ng-invalid.ng-touched) {
    border-color:red;
}
```